# What is a fulltext index and when should I use it?

Tags: mysql

As the title states, what is a fulltext index and when should I use it?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

In databases indices are usually used to enhance performance when looking for something defined in your where clause. However when it comes to filtering some text, e.g. using something like `WHERE TextColumn LIKE '%searchstring%'` then searches are slow, because the way regular database indices work are optimized for matches against the 'whole content' of a column and not just a part of it. In specific the LIKE search which includes wildcards can not make use of any kind of index.

As mentioned in the comment below MySQL needs the `MATCH () ... AGAINST` syntax to search within a fulltext index; BTW this varies depending on the database vendor. In MS SQL you can use `CONTAINS` so keep this in mind when you plan to support other databases too.

Fulltext indices work better for regular text, because they are optimized for these type of columns. Very simplified: They split the text into words and make an index over the words and not the whole text. This works a lot faster for text searches when looking for specific words.

Comment: So in other words, if you _are_ looking for an exact match against the entire string, a FULLTEXT index is the wrong thing to use?

Comment: @aroth when searching over the whole column content a fulltext index would not be beneficial at all, yes.

Comment: "because the way regular database indices work are optimized for matches against the 'whole content' of a column and not just a part of it. In specific the LIKE search can not make use of any kind of index." - This statement is not true. Indexes do work with LIKE search when there is no leading wild card.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898453/does-index-on-varchar-make-performance-difference

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905125/mysql-improve-search-performance-with-wildcards

Answer (score 17):

A full text index is an index you apply in a MySQL database to text fields that you plan to run a full text search on.  A full text search uses the `match(field) against('text')` syntax.  If you want to run a full text search you must have a full text index on the columns you'll be running it against.

There are three types of Full Text searches.  I'll quote the manual, because I think it says it best:

> - A boolean search interprets the search string using the rules of a
>     special query language. The string
>     contains the words to search for. It
>     can also contain operators that
>     specify requirements such that a word
>     must be present or absent in matching
>     rows, or that it should be weighted
>     higher or lower than usual. Common
>     words such as “some” or “then” are
>     stopwords and do not match if present
>     in the search string. The IN BOOLEAN
>     MODE modifier specifies a boolean
>     search. For more information, see
>     Section 11.9.2, “Boolean Full-Text
>     Searches”.
> - A natural language search interprets the search string as a
>     phrase in natural human language (a
>     phrase in free text). There are no
>     special operators. The stopword list
>     applies. In addition, words that are
>     present in 50% or more of the rows are
>     considered common and do not match.
>     Full-text searches are natural
>     language searches if no modifier is
>     given.
> - A query expansion search is a modification of a natural language
>     search. The search string is used to
>     perform a natural language search.
>     Then words from the most relevant rows
>     returned by the search are added to
>     the search string and the search is
>     done again. The query returns the rows
>     from the second search. The WITH QUERY
>     EXPANSION modifier specifies a query
>     expansion search. For more
>     information, see Section 11.9.3,
>     “Full-Text Searches with Query
>     Expansion”.

For more information take a gander at the [Full Text Search Reference Page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html).