# Mysql Improve Search Performance with wildcards (%%)

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-optimization

Below is a query I use for searching a person by email

```
  SELECT *
    FROM phppos_customers
    JOIN phppos_people ON phppos_customers.person_id = phppos_people.person_id
   WHERE deleted = 0
     AND email LIKE '%f%'
ORDER BY email ASC
```

Will adding an index on "email" speed up the query?

Comment: [That explaination](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/like-performance-tuning) might help to understand why it's not working.

Comment: [**This answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22531268/793309) shows a nice technique - indexing all suffixes - that can make this kind of query perform very well, but at the cost of some extra coding and greater storage requirements.

Comment: Yes, this is possible; you can use an n-gram full-text index: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74956857/2299084

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No, because MySQL will not be able to utilize the index when you have a leading wildcard. If you changed your LIKE to 'f%', then it would be able to use the index.

Answer (score 10):

Wildcarding the left side of a `LIKE` operation ensures that an index, if one exists on the `email` column, can not be used.

Full Text Search (FTS) is preferred syntax for finding strings within text via SQL.  [MySQL has native FTS functionality, using the MATCH/AGAINST syntax (Requires the table to use the MyISAM engine for v.5.5 and below. InnoDB FTS supported on v.5.6+)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html):

```
  SELECT c.*, p.*
    FROM PHPPOS_CUSTOMERS c
    JOIN PHPPOS_PEOPLE p ON p.person_id = c..person_id
   WHERE deleted = 0
     AND MATCH(email) AGAINST('f')
ORDER BY email
```

But there are third party FTS technology, such as Sphinx.

Comment: I detailed the FULLTEXT and talked a bit about Sphynx here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338889/how-to-find-similar-results-and-sort-by-similarity/3339034#3339034

Comment: As of MySQL 5.6 FTS functionality is now available on InnoDB tables.

Comment: This is pretty useless, since FTS adds full words to index, whilst wildcard %% allows you to do partial search. There is ngram type of FTS index for MySQL, but it's quite useless to whilst trying to replicate: %% behaviour, since it doesn't support min/max ngram size (as e.g. ElasticSearch do), just the one `ngram_token_size`.

Comment: There is a way to shoehorn FTS into performing partial matches on both sides: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74956857/2299084

Answer (score 8):

No, `Mysql` will not use the index because `LIKE` argument (`%f%`) starts with the wildcard character `%`.
If it starts with a constant, index will be used.

More info: [*7.5.3. How MySQL Uses Indexes*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Answer (score 4):

In my post here I describe, in detail, a technique that allows you to **use the index** with `LIKE` for fast **`%infix%` search**, at the cost of some extra storage:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22531268/543814

As long as the strings are relatively small, the storage requirement is generally acceptable.

According to Google, the average e-mail address is `25` characters long. This increases your required storage by a factor `12.5` on average, and gives you fast indexed search in return. (See my post for the calculations.)

From my perspective, if you are storing 10'000 e-mail addresses, you should be fine storing (the equivalent of) about 100'000 e-mail addresses, too. If this is what it takes to allow you to use an index, that seems like an acceptable trade-off. Often, disk space is cheap, while non-indexed searches are unaffordable.

If you choose to take this approach, I suggest that you limit the input length of e-mail addresses to `64` characters. Those rare (or attacker) e-mail addresses of such length will require up to `32` times the usual storage. This gives you:

1. Protection against an attacker trying to flood your database, since these still aren't very impressive amounts of data.
2. The expectation that most e-mail addresses are not of this length anyway.

If you consider `64` characters too harsh a requirement, use `255` instead, for a worst-case storage increase factor of `127.5`. Ridiculous? Possibly. Likely? No. Fast? Very.

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to make it faster with `LIKE` just like everyone says (about the `%` at the beginning), but you can improve it a little by joining after you filter your people first.

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT * 
          FROM `phppos_customers`
         WHERE `deleted` = 0
           AND  `email`  LIKE '%f%') `t_customers`
  JOIN `phppos_people` ON `t_customers`.`person_id`=`phppos_people`.`person_id`
 ORDER BY `email` asc
```

Comment: Using the `LIKE` with a left side wildcard in a derived table/inline view still won't use an index...

Comment: The OP asks specifically about index use...  I'm inclined to downvote, being that you're aware you don't provide anything of value to the question...

Comment: I clearly answered "no" because of the `LIKE` (edited and clarified for your enjoyment), and provided an "improvement" on the query. Now, it may not answer the original question, but does provide helpful information about speed gain on a query. Now, what in that deserves a downvote?

Comment: Your speculative belief that this is an improvement is not enough - explain plans matter.

Answer (score -3):

I know how to outsmart mysql and enable the index search even when wild card searching from the left side. Just create a reversed column of your column (make it an index), reverse also the search string, and use the wildcard from right side which has the index support..

So if you have in db word "slibro" and you want search "%libro", created reversed column will contain "orbils" and search will be "orbil%".

PS: But don't have the solution how to do fast full wildcard search "%x%" though :).

Comment: This will not work as the first search will not find any valid results if the word to be found is there inside the string at any place other than the first one. PS: I tried to do this and it failed me miserably.