# Wildcard search in MySQL full-text search

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, wildcard

Let's say we have the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM companies
WHERE name LIKE '%nited'
```

It returns

| name |
| --- |
| united |

How do I write a query using [MySQL's full-text search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html) that will provide similar results?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do this using a MySQL full-text index. You cannot retrieve `'*nited states'` instantly from index because left characters are the most important part of the index. However, you **can** search `'United Sta*'`.

```
// the only possible wildcard full-text search in MySQL
WHERE MATCH(column) AGAINST ('United Sta*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

MySQL's full-text performs best when searching whole words in sentences - even that can suck at times. Otherwise, I'd suggest using an external full-text engine like [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) or [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/). I think Sphinx allows prefix and suffix wildcards, not sure about the others.

You could go back to MySQL's `LIKE` clause, but again, running queries like `LIKE '%nited states'` or `LIKE '%nited Stat%'`, will also suffer on performance, as it can't use the index on the first few characters. `'United Sta%'` and `'Unit%States'` are okay as the index can be used against the first bunch of known characters.

Another quite major caveat using MySQL's full-text indexing is the stop-word list and [minimum word length settings](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html). For example, on a shared hosting environment, you will be limited to words greater than or equal to 4-characters. So searching 'Goo' to get 'Google' would fail. [The stop-word list](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) also disallows common words like 'and', 'maybe' and 'outside' - in-fact, there are 548 stop-words all together! Again, if not using shared hosting, these settings are relatively easily to modify, but if you are, then you will get annoyed with some of the default settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySQL's full-text index, but you must configure the parser to be [the n-gram parser](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search-ngram.html).

If your data is English (as opposed to Chinese or similar), you ought to also increase the `ngram_token_size` parameter to the minimum search term length you are willing to have. Otherwise, the search will be unacceptably slow.

You will also want to set `innodb_ft_enable_stopword=0`, otherwise an [idiosyncrasy of how ngram stopword handling works will](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search-ngram.html#idm45750411652608) mean that many useful queries will return no results.

To explain why you must also increase `ngram_token_size`, you may think of this index as the following schema. MySQL then does a series of joins to find the results which match the search term:

```
CREATE TABLE fulltext_index
(
    docid int(11) NOT NULL,
    term  char(2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (docid, term),
    INDEX term_idx (term)
);
```

The n-gram (2) parser breaks each word in your query into segments like `se`, `eg`, `gm`, `me`, `en`, `nt`, `ts`. For each of these n-grams, there are many results in English, so the index doesn't help much since it ends up iterating over everything anyway. Meanwhile, you can see how Chinese `随机的` would split into a much more useful `随机` and `机的`. With n-gram size set to 4, the segments are  `segm`, `egme`, `gmen`, `ment`, `ents`. These larger segments are much more likely to be unique, so each segment narrows down the search space significantly.

Disabling stopwords is also necessary because the [ngram parser excludes all n-grams that contain](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search-ngram.html#idm45750411652608) any of [the stopwords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html#fulltext-stopwords-stopwords-for-innodb-search-indexes). For example, with an n-gram (4) parser, `stopword` will be parsed into `stop`, `topw`, `opwr`, `pwor`, and `word`:

- `stop` will be excluded because it contains "to"
- `topw` will be excluded because it contains "to"
- `opwr` will be kept
- `pwor` will be excluded because it contains "or"
- `word` will be excluded because it contains "or"

Because these tokens are excluded from the index, a search for `MATCH(name) AGAINST('stop' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` would not return anything unless the stopwords mechanism is disabled before creating the index.

---

To answer your question,

1. set `ngram_token_size` to 3, 4, or whatever your minimum search term length is.
2. set `innodb_ft_enable_stopword` to `0` or `OFF`.
3. create the index with `CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX companies_name_idx ON companies (name) WITH PARSER ngram;`
4. `SELECT * FROM companies WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST('nited' IN BOOLEAN MODE);`

This will also return results for `nitedA`, so you might want to further filter the results from there, if that's required for your application.

Comment: I'm using FULLTEXT search and appending the string with wildcard * makes no difference. It still only matches whole words. Could it be because of the n-gram parser?