# MySQL fulltext search not returning all matching results

Tags: sql, mysql, full-text-search, mysql-8.0, fulltext-index

I'm using MySQL 8 and I've got a table called `records` for which I added the following index in order to perform text search on it:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX all_records_idx ON records (`title`, `label`, `description`, `catalog_number`,`barcode`);
```

Now, I've got the following data (copied it as JSON):

```
[
  {
    "barcode": "79027066021",
    "title": "White Blood Cells",
    "slug": "White-blood-cells",
    "image": null,
    "description": "rev",
    "artist_id": 3,
    "genre_id": 1,
    "num_of_records": 1,
    "original_release_year": 2001,
    "original_release_date": null,
    "reissue_release_date": null,
    "label": null,
    "sleeve_side_color": "ff1500",
    "vinyl_color": "ff1500",
    "size": 12,
    "barcode_in_record": null,
    "catalog_number": null,
    "owned_copies": 1,
    "active": 1,
    "created_at": "2023-06-11 21:32:17.000",
    "updated_at": null,
    "deleted_at": null
  },
  {
    "barcode": "889854036119",
    "title": "Nilsson Schmilsson",
    "slug": "nilsson-schmilsson",
    "image": null,
    "description": null,
    "artist_id": 6,
    "genre_id": 1,
    "num_of_records": 1,
    "original_release_year": 1971,
    "original_release_date": null,
    "reissue_release_date": null,
    "label": null,
    "sleeve_side_color": "490d57",
    "vinyl_color": "000000",
    "size": 12,
    "barcode_in_record": null,
    "catalog_number": null,
    "owned_copies": 1,
    "active": 1,
    "created_at": "2023-06-11 21:32:17.000",
    "updated_at": null,
    "deleted_at": null
  },
  {
    "barcode": "C10777774644617",
    "title": "Abbey Road",
    "slug": "abbey-road",
    "image": null,
    "description": null,
    "artist_id": 2,
    "genre_id": 1,
    "num_of_records": 1,
    "original_release_year": 1969,
    "original_release_date": null,
    "reissue_release_date": null,
    "label": null,
    "sleeve_side_color": "46518f",
    "vinyl_color": "000000",
    "size": 12,
    "barcode_in_record": null,
    "catalog_number": null,
    "owned_copies": 1,
    "active": 1,
    "created_at": "2023-06-11 21:32:17.000",
    "updated_at": null,
    "deleted_at": null
  },
  {
    "barcode": "C10777774644618",
    "title": "Revolver",
    "slug": "revolver",
    "image": null,
    "description": null,
    "artist_id": 2,
    "genre_id": 1,
    "num_of_records": 1,
    "original_release_year": 1966,
    "original_release_date": null,
    "reissue_release_date": null,
    "label": null,
    "sleeve_side_color": "46518f",
    "vinyl_color": "000000",
    "size": 12,
    "barcode_in_record": null,
    "catalog_number": null,
    "owned_copies": 1,
    "active": 1,
    "created_at": "2023-06-11 21:32:17.000",
    "updated_at": null,
    "deleted_at": null
  },
  {
    "barcode": "C10777774644619",
    "title": "arevolat",
    "slug": "aurevolat",
    "image": null,
    "description": "this is a test",
    "artist_id": 2,
    "genre_id": 1,
    "num_of_records": 1,
    "original_release_year": 1999,
    "original_release_date": null,
    "reissue_release_date": null,
    "label": null,
    "sleeve_side_color": null,
    "vinyl_color": null,
    "size": 12,
    "barcode_in_record": null,
    "catalog_number": null,
    "owned_copies": 1,
    "active": 1,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "deleted_at": null
  }
]
```

So, there are currently 5 records in the table. In order to test the search functionality, I ran the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM records WHERE MATCH(`title`, `label`, `description`, `catalog_number`,`barcode`)
AGAINST ('*rev*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I was expecting to get 3 records back:

- 1 for barcode 79027066021 where it should match to the description "description": "rev".
- 1 for barcode C10777774644618 where it should match to the title "title": "Revolver".
- 1 for barcode C10777774644619 where it should match to the title "title": "arevolat".

But I'm only getting back the first two records:

- 1 for barcode 79027066021 where it should match to the description "description": "rev".
- 1 for barcode C10777774644618 where it should match to the title "title": "Revolver".

This one is not present:

- 1 for barcode C10777774644619 where it should match to the title "title": "arevolat".

Even though I'm using `*` as part of the search.

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE `records` (
  `barcode` varchar(48) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(160) NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(191) DEFAULT NULL,
  `artist_id` bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `genre_id` bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `num_of_records` bigint NOT NULL,
  `original_release_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `reissue_release_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `label` longtext,
  `sleeve_side_color` varchar(191) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vinyl_color` longtext,
  `size` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `barcode_in_record` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `catalog_number` longtext,
  `owned_copies` bigint DEFAULT '1',
  `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `created_at` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `original_release_year` bigint NOT NULL,
  `description` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`barcode`),
  UNIQUE KEY `barcode` (`barcode`),
  UNIQUE KEY `slug` (`slug`),
  KEY `fk_records_artist` (`artist_id`),
  KEY `fk_records_genre` (`genre_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `all_records_idx` (`title`,`label`,`description`,`catalog_number`,`barcode`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_records_artist` FOREIGN KEY (`artist_id`) REFERENCES `artists` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_records_genre` FOREIGN KEY (`genre_id`) REFERENCES `genres` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Any idea what's going on?

Thanks

Comment: what is the data type of the title column? Do you have a ddl to create the table?

Comment: @Elbo Shindi Pangestu -- (There is no ver 8.2.  The default len is 3.  On the other hand, the generated-LIKE query was impressive for GPT.)

Comment: @rob2000 added the DDL

Answer (score 2):

"%", "*", and other punctuation marks have specific and *different* meanings for `AGAINST`, `LIKE`, and `RLIKE`.

```
MATCH(title, ...) AGAINST('*rev*')  -- ignores the leading punctuation mark
title LIKE '%rev%'  -- finds the desired 3 rows, but only in `title`; and slow
title RLIKE 'rev'  -- finds the desired 3 rows, but only in `title`; and slow
title LIKE '%rev%' OR label LIKE '%rev%' OR ... -- even slower
```

FULLTEXT, when appropriate, is almost always faster than `LIKE` or `RLIKE`; often *much* faster.  I suggest you change the requirements and/or expectations.  As you see from above, there is no syntax that is both simple and fast.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, the wildcard character is `%` rather than `*`.

Try `AGAINST ('%rev%' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

Sometimes, `*` acts as a modifier to match 'zero or more instances of the thing preceding it.'

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html

However, the above Pattern Matching applies to the extended regular expressions (such as when using `RLIKE`).

For a Boolean Full-text Search, the `*` is a truncation operator.  The * at the end of your expression means that `rev` must be present at the start of one or more words.  This explains the missing record in your results.

I suspect the first `*` is ignored.

More info: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Comment: I tried this `AGAINST ('%rev%' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` but didn't work

Comment: The FULLTEXT search works by indexing the start of each word.
Imagine looking in a dictionary for words starting with REV, you'll find them all very quickly.  However, if you try to find all words containing REV, you'd have to check every page.  Here's a previous answer that appears to confirm that you can't use a wildcard prefix in a full-text search. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20680736

Comment: "* acts as a modifier to match 'zero or more instances of the thing preceding it.'" -- That applies to RLIKE, not Fulltext and not LIKE.

Comment: Nice pickup, Rick!
After four example queries all using LIKE, the docs talk about a different approach (e.g. RLIKE) without so much as a heading.
I've learned something today. :)

Answer (score 1):

> **12.9.5 Full-Text Restrictions**
>
> The '%' character is not a supported wildcard character for full-text searches.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-restrictions.html

> Asterisk *
>
> The asterisk serves as the truncation (or wildcard) operator. Unlike
> the other operators, it is appended to the word to be affected. **Words
> match if they begin with the word preceding the * operator.**
> [...]
>
> The wildcarded word is considered as a prefix that must be present at
> the start of one or more words.[...]
>
> **The following examples demonstrate some search strings that use boolean full-text operators:** [...]
>
> 'apple*'
>
> Find rows that contain words such as “apple”, “apples”, “applesauce”, or “applet”.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html