# How to make query faster with group by and order by

Tags: mysql

I have large table with 615 million records in items and 10 thousand in markets

the below query takes 5+ seconds to execute

how can I make it faster. ?

```
SELECT items.name,items.ID as itemID,items.market_id as market_id,markets.name as marketname 
from items,markets 
where markets.ID = items.market_id and 
items.name like '%bab%' 
group by items.name 
order by items.name ASC 
limit 0,10
```

Explain

[image]

```
-> Limit: 10 row(s)  (actual time=4657.094..4657.096 rows=9 loops=1)

-> Sort: items.`name`, limit input to 10 row(s) per chunk  (actual time=4657.093..4657.094 rows=9 loops=1)

-> Table scan on <temporary>  (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=9 loops=1)

-> Temporary table with deduplication  (cost=1141592.47 rows=625722) 
(actual time=4657.070..4657.072 rows=9 loops=1)

-> Nested loop inner join  (cost=1141592.47 rows=625722) (actual time=0.056..4541.471 rows=85329 loops=1)

-> Filter: (items.`name` like \'%bab%\')  (cost=593647.14 rows=625722) (actual time=0.043..4456.394 rows=85329 loops=1)

-> Table scan on items  (cost=593647.14 rows=5632061) (actual time=0.037..2864.754 rows=6153656 loops=1)

-> Single-row index lookup on markets using PRIMARY (ID=items.market_id)  (cost=0.78 rows=1) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=85329)
```

Comment: Please add info from `EXPLAIN ANALYZE <your sql statement>`

Comment: Your query is likely invalid assuming that `items.name` is not the primary key.  Also, you have a `LIKE` condition in your where clause which is not sargable.  This will make it hard to optimize your query.  And finally, I don't see the point of using `GROUP BY` here, since you select no aggregates.

Comment: From the picture (and from the comment Tim B. gave) it was already clear that `Table scan on items` is the cause of your problem.

Comment: @Luuk so how do I re write the query to make it faster ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905125/mysql-improve-search-performance-with-wildcards the reason for a full table scan is you are doing a "contains" that mysql cannot utilize the index when you have aleading wildcard. How long does `like 'bab%'` take (this is a starts with) ?

Comment: @Rippo its takes 2+seconds  which is better but not ideal

Comment: @Rippo will FTS be better solution ? change name column to text and do a match ?

Comment: @skcrpk did you read the answer to the link I sent, any FTS using a leading wildcard is goinf to take a long time, even removing it still takes time on 165M rows.

Comment: @Rippo yes I did read that and tried to implement I was able to change the column to text and add a full text index it took long but result still took 2 seconds same as using ‘bab%’ as it utilises indexs in this case

Comment: The query is poorly formed if there are multiple rows for a given `name`.  The query would not even complete on 8.0.  To phrase it another way, _which_ `market_id` and items.ID` do you want to display when you group by items.name?

Comment: @RickJames I will add tables schema in few hours so you can suggest a better approach ?

Comment: `MIN(market_id)`?  AVG(market_id) (I doubt it)?  GROUP_CONCAT(market_id)?

Answer (score 0):

You might get a (small !?) improvement, when you do this:

```
SELECT items.name,items.ID as itemID,items.market_id as market_id,markets.name as marketname 
from items
inner join markets on markets.ID = items.market_id
where markets.ID IN (SELECT items.market_id 
                     FROM marketd
                     WHERE items.name like '%bab%' 
                     order by items.name ASC 
                     limit 0,10)
order by items.name
```

EDIT: oops, that's tru you cannot do LIMIT in a subquery....

If you have MySQL 8.0+, you can do:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT items.market_id 
   FROM marketd
   WHERE items.name like '%bab%' 
   order by items.name ASC 
   limit 0,10
)
SELECT items.name,items.ID as itemID,items.market_id as market_id,markets.name as marketname 
from items
inner join markets on markets.ID = items.market_id
where markets.ID IN ( SELECT market_id 
                      FROM cte )
order by items.name;
```

also, you might need to add an index on `market_id`, if that does not exists yet. With that, the cte will use that index.

Comment: getting , Error Code: 1235. This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: edit done, because of the limit which cannot be used in a subquery

Comment: it still took too much time but most importantly the result is not same as the original query

Answer (score 0):

This should work with any version of MySQL at least since 5.0:

```
SELECT items.name,
       items.ID as itemID,
       items.market_id as market_id,
       ( SELECT markets.name 
              FROM markets WHERE markets.ID = items.market_id
       ) as marketname 
    FROM items
    WHERE items.name like '%bab%' 
    ORDER BY items.name ASC 
    LIMIT 10
```

That should eliminate the `GROUP BY`.

Indexes:

```
items:  (name, ID, market_id)
markets:  presumably `ID` is the PRIMARY KEY
```

Comment: it returns same items.names but when I add group by to your query it returns different items.name , which is what I want  , I have created suggested index but that is not being used , still query takes more than 4+ seconds with group by and without it takes 3+ seconds

Comment: @skcrpk - by "same items.names", you mean duplicates?

Comment: Not duplicate each market can have same name items

Comment: Then which market_id should be displayed after you group by the name?