# Speed up rails like query

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I speed up string matching query which uses SQL `like`? The code looks something like

```
CurrentSchool.all.includes(:school).where(is_middle_school: true).where("name like '%#{search}%'")
```

This is search box suggestion query that has to fast for good UX.

Comment: Which DB are you using? Is the `name` field indexed?

Comment: I am using MySQL DB. Would adding an index on column improve like performance?

Comment: how big is your DB ?

Comment: Try using `CurrentSchool.all.includes(:school).where(is_middle_school: true).where("name like '%#{search}%'").explain`. It will display how many rows are examined. After adding an index, you can run it again and see whether the number of rows has been reduced

Comment: You should write `.where("name like '%#{search}%'")` as `.where("name like ?", "'%#{search}%'")`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481528/mysql-like-performance-boost  suggests that index is only useful if query is '#{search}%'

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [fulltext index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3645859/5379362) to get a performance boost using a `'%something%'` like query.