# How should I store different kinds of posts in SQL? (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance, database-design

I'm trying to optimize my PHP and MySQL, but my understanding of SQL databases is shoddy at best. I'm creating a website (mostly for learning purposes) which allows users to make different kinds of posts (image/video/text/link).

Here is the basics of what I'm storing

1. **Auto** - *int* (key index)
2. **User ID** - *varchar*
3. **Post id** - *varchar*
4. **Post Type** - *varchar* (YouTube, vimeo, image, text, link)
5. **File Name** - *varchar* (original image name or link title)
6. **Source** - *varchar* (external link or name of file + ext)
7. **Title** - *varchar* (post title picked by user)
8. **Message** - *text* (user's actual post)
9. **Date** - *int* (unix timestamp)

I have other data stored relevant to the post in other tables which I grab with the post id (like user information) but I'm really doubting if this is the method I should be storing information in. I do use PDO, but I'm afraid this format might just be extremely slow.

Would there be any sense in storing the post information in another format? I don't want excessively large tables, so from a performance standpoint should I store some information as a blob/binary/xml/json?

I can't seem to find any good resources on PHP/MySQL optimization. Most information I come across tends to be 5-10 years old, content you have to pay for, too low-level, or just straight documentation which can't hold my attention for more than half an hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have seems okay, but you have missed the important bit about indexes and keys.

Firstly, I am assuming that your primary key will be field 1. Okay, no problems there, but make sure that you also stick an index on userID, PostID, Date and probably a composite on UserID, Date.

Secondly, are you planning on having search functions on these? In that case you may need to enable full text searches.

Don't muck around trying to store data in a JSON or other such things. Store it plain and simple. The last thing you want to be doing is trying to extract a field from the database just to see what is inside. If you database can't work it out, it is bad design.

On that note, there isn't anything *wrong* with large tables. As long as they are indexed nicely, a small table or large table will make very little difference in terms of accessing it (short of huge badly written SQL joins), so worry about simplicity to be able to *get* the data back from it.

Edit: A Primary Key is lovely way to identify a row by a unique column of some sort. So, if you want to delete a row, in your example, you might specify a `delete from yourTable where ID=6` and you know that this will only delete *one* row as only one row can have ID=6.

On the other hand, an index is different to a key, in that it is like a cheat-sheet for the database to know where certain information is inside the table. For example, if you have an index on the UserID column, when you pass a userID in a query, the database won't have to look though the entire table, it looks at the index and knows the location of all the rows for that user.

A composite index is taking this one step further again, if you know what you will want to constantly query data for both UserID and ContentType, you can add in a composite index (meaning an index on BOTH fields in one index) which will then allow the database to return only the data you specify in a query using both those columns without having to sift through the entire table - nor even sift through all of a users posts to find the right content type.

Now, indexes take up some extra space on the server, so keep that in mind, but if your tables grow to be larger (which is perfectly fine) the improved efficiency is staggering.

Comment: Sorry, the "Auto increment" is an index (called auto) I'll fix it to make that more clear.

Comment: @Ian Yeah, that's fine. You still want indexes on the other columns as well though, they will make a VAST difference to your queries efficiency.

Comment: Wait, how do I index other keys? My assumption was that you just added an increment column which was applied to every post. Also I do have have full-text search functionality set up and working.

Answer (score 3):

Databases are made to store 'data', and are fast to retrieve the data. Do not switch to anything else, stick with a database.

Try not to store pictures and video's in a database. Store them on disk, and keep a reference to them in a database table.

Finally, catch up on database [normalization](http://www.w3schools.in/mysql/database-normalization/), it will help you in getting your database in optimal condition.

Answer (score 1):

At this time, stick with RDMS for now. Once you will be comfortable with PHP and MySQL then may be later on there will be more to learn like NoSQL, MongoDB etc. but for current purpose of yours as every thing has its purpose, this is quite right and will not slow down. Your table schema seems right with few modifications.

User id and Post id will be integer and I think this table is post so post id will be auto incremented and it will be primary key.

Other thing is that you are using 2 fields, filename and source, please note that filename will be file's name that is uploaded but if by source you mean complete path of file then then DB is not the place for storing complete path. Generate path from PHP function. to access that path every time not in DB. Otherwise if you will need to change path then it will be much overhead.

Also you asked about blob etc. Please note that it is better to store file in file system not in db while these fields like blob etc are good when one want to store file in DB table, that I don't recommend here.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The User ID and Post ID are randomly generated and alphanumeric, which is why I store them as varchar. My users table has an auto incrementing id as well as an alphanumeric id. I do this primarily for the sake of consistent looking URLs. Also the files could be both external or local, so I just contain a reference to the file name if it's local and the full URL if not since I couldn't think of a better way to do it.

Comment: @lan yes then that makes sense and your schema is fine but is that user_id is foreign key that will come from some other table?

Comment: In any table I create where I reference a user I use the user_id rather than the increment associated in the user table. I didn't think it would make a difference since it is a direct reference to the user. Is there a reason I should be using the key instead?

Comment: there is may be a very little difference when foreign key will be varchar, please see 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898453/does-index-on-varchar-make-performance-difference