# text input or select?

Tags: database, user-input

when creating an application for students management for a private school, when adding a student the user must specify from which public school the student comes, after that the application shows information about students according to the school they came from, the problem i face is when the user enters different names for the same school (eg: "abc-paris", "abc/paris" and "abc paris" will be considered as 3 different schools which is not), the solution i think about is to make a select instead of sample text input (in html) but i find this a bad solution because :

- the list of schools may changes in the future so i need to create a
  database table that contains the names of the school.
- i need to do some extra work for managing(adding,deleting) a school.
- i find it bad to create a database table that contains only one column.

so do you have any better solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your data model is not normalised.  I think you should have a list of schools in a lookup table.  There should be a one to many relationship between school and student.  On the user interface the school should be a drop down box rather than a textbox.

Here is a suggested table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE School (ID int identity, Name varchar(30), primary key (ID))
CREATE TABLE Student (ID int, SchoolID INT, primary key (ID),
FOREIGN KEY (SchoolID) REFERENCES School(Id))

INSERT INTO School (Name) VALUES ('School1')
INSERT INTO School (Name) VALUES ('School2')
INSERT INTO School (Name) VALUES ('School3')

INSERT INTO Student (id,SchoolID) VALUES (1,1)
INSERT INTO Student (id,SchoolID) VALUES (2,1)
INSERT INTO Student (id,SchoolID) VALUES (3,2)
INSERT INTO Student (id,SchoolID) VALUES (4,3)
INSERT INTO Student (id,SchoolID) VALUES (5,3)
INSERT INTO Student (id,SchoolID) VALUES (6,3)
```

Notice there are two schools and six students.  Two of those students goes to school 1, one student goes to school 2 and three students go to school 3.

The user interface should contain a drop down box for the user to select a school i.e. SELECT ID, Name FROM School.  Name should be displayed in the drop down box for each school and ID used to select the school/insert the school into the database.

Comment: the school contains only one information (one column) which is the name this why i have put it as a column in the student table, is there any rule for normalizing a database model that says it's false to put the school name in the student table

Comment: @user2080105, I have edited my answer with a suggested table structure.  Note you will have to set auto identity to on for both tables.  If you don't know how to do this then let me know.

Comment: thank you, but one more important question, why sould i use an id for the School table if i am sure that the name is unique (there is no schools with the same name), so the school name works fine as a primary key without adding an extra attribute (id) !

Comment: There could be data quality errors if you do not separate the table, for example what happens if one user enters Scool1 another enters Skhool1 and another enters School1.  That is three separate records for one school.  The school name is not functionally dependent on the student ID.

Comment: I agree with the separation, but why the school table contains 2 columns instead of one, why adding the attribute id if the school name can work fine as a primary key

Comment: One of the reasons is for better performance with indexes according to Leigh S's answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898453/does-index-on-varchar-make-performance-difference