# best mysql data type for storing barcode and searching in it

Tags: mysql, indexing, barcode

I use varchar for saving barcode in my database and the index is set for this field for better result in search.
But the response time is a bit longer and we need to decrease the result time.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have an index on that field, the query should be as fast as it can be. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1898511/488012). Just make sure that MySQL is choosing that index.

Of course, if your barcodes are always of the same length you would be better off with a Char(N) datatype.